# Change the z-index of jQuery ui-resizable-handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to change the z-index rule of the ui-resizable handle of jQuery. Those handles spawn when you call .resizable() on a DOM object.

I searched on stackoverflow and i found an answer, but it's not working anymore (the css files have changed).

The final goal is to make a div pop above an handle.. i also tried to put the max z-index which is 2147483647 on my div, but it didn't work ...

Comment: I tried to search in jquery-ui.js and i found an option "z-index" in resizable, but it don't work...

Comment: Does the element have a position set? z-index only works on elements with relative, fixed or absolute position that has explicitly been set.

Comment: I found my problem when i was creating  fiddle for.. It was about another script on the page which edit the z-index of my element too... Sorry for this.